# Symfony2: event changes into listener

Tags: php, events, symfony, listener

My "CustomEvent(.php)" class that's set in my "CustomListeren(.php)" as $event property.

On kernel.terminate the $event property changes from "CustomEvent" to "CustomListener" (empty object).

```
# CustomEvent.php
namespace Stackoverflow\AwesomeBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class CustomEvent extends Event {

  protected $data;

  /**
   * @param Data $data
   */
  public function __construct(Data $data) {
    $this->data = $data;
  }

  /**
   * @return Data
   */
  public function getdata() {
    return $this->data;
  }
}
```

and

```
# CustomListener.php
namespace Stackoverflow\AwesomeBundle\Event;

class CustomListener {
  /**
   * @var CustomEvent
   */
  protected $event;

  /**
   * @param CustomEvent $event
   */
  public function firstTrigger(CustomEvent $event) {
    // indeed instanceof CustomEvent
    $this->event = $event;
  }

  public function secondTrigger() {
    // $this->event is now instanceof CustomListener instead of CustomEvent

    if ($this->event instanceof CustomEvent) {
      // ... code logic
    }
  }
}
```

my controller

```
# CustomController
namespace Stackoverflow\AwesomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Stackoverflow\AwesomeBundle\Data;
use Stackoverflow\AwesomeBundle\Event\CustomEvent;

class CustomController extends Controller {
  public function customAction(Request $request) {
   // ... code

   $data = new Data();

   $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(
     'nameIsNotImportant',
     new CustomEvent($data)
   );

   // ... code
  }
}
```

my bundle services.yml

```
parameters:
  custom.listener.class: Stackoverflow\AwesomeBundle\Event\CustomListener

services:
  custom_listener:
    class: %custom.listener.class%
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: nameIsNotImportant, method: firsTrigger }
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.terminate, method: secondTrigger }
```

I did a get_class($this->event) in CustomListener::secondTrigger()
The logs show that $this->event changed into CustomListener

```
[2014-04-25 15:20:16] app.DEBUG: Pointer\Revlect\SecurityBundle\Event\ResetTokenEvent [] []
...
[2014-04-25 15:20:16] app.DEBUG: Pointer\Revlect\SecurityBundle\Event\ResetTokenListener [] []
[2014-04-25 15:20:16] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Stackoverflow\AwesomeBundle\Event\CustomListener::secondTrigger". [] []
```

In CustomListener::secondTrigger() $this->event must be instanceof CustomEvent.
Do I miss a puzzle piece???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my method-name from "sendMail" into "sendsMail"..

So if you encounter such issue try changing your method name.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use two listeners with one action instead of that listener with two actions. That should fix this.

You are using two different Event classes in one single Listener, and in `SecondTrigger()` you are not defining the `$event` it will receive, so `$this->event` is not defined correctly.

Best option is to use two listeners for two events, but if you want to use only one listener after all, you should define the `$event` you're waiting for at `secondTrigger()`.